# paypal-apps.com is not working?

Tags: paypal, paypal-nvp, nvp

Maybe someone knows what the cause of the error? I am trying to come and continue the activation of your NVP / SOAP API Apps, but the server responds with an error. Someone knows what's going on?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLq0h.png)

Comment: Please provide more information and show what you have tried so far

Comment: thank you for quick response.
I go into the Dashboard page at developer.paypal.com --> My Apps & Sredentials.
Click on the link Create and manage NVP / SOAP API apps. in section NVP / SOAP API APPS and get on the error page.

Comment: so someone knows what's going on with the application management server paypal?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: It looks like over the weekend the app services went back online, so all should be fixed now. Let me know if you encounter any issues with it, and definitely very sorry for any issues this downtime caused you.

At the moment there are some issues at paypal-apps.com, which is affecting the site and ability to create new applications. The teams are working on the servers that are affected and will hopefully have more information soon. I'll update as soon as I have more details though.